# How to create my own System namespace and objects?

Tags: c#

It is said here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa13yay7%28v=VS.90%29.aspx (see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4wcexbc%28VS.90%29.aspx)

> Use this option if you want to define
>   or create your own System namespace
>   and objects.

But how ? Where can I find some examples ?

Update: of course my question is not about how to create a namespace or a class but about an example of custom system architecture (an UML schema and source code).

For example could this be used to port .NET on other processors like iphone ? Does Mono use this ?

Is there some smallest possible example instead of whole commercial clr to learn from ?

Comment: You don't know how to define a class?  Or use a namespace?

Comment: Umm those links tell you exactly how to do it... After following their directions simply make a namespace called System and start programming.

Comment: If you don't know how to do it, you probably don't need to...

Comment: Sure I know how to create a namespace or class. My question is more about how to create my OWN ARCHITECTURE and so want to see some example.

Comment: The desktop CLR frameworks class library is an example. The Silverlight CLR frameworks class library is an example. The Compact Framework class library is an example. There are *lots* of examples of frameworks out there.

Comment: What I mean by examples is UML Schemas and source code so where are they ?

Comment: This might be interesting: http://lightnet.codeplex.com/ It is a template for building your own std. lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do that but you just have to create a custom "System" assembly (like a standard library) and use it as a reference in your other project with `/nostdlib+` set.

```
namespace System 
{
  public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that you have to also implement: System.Object, Byte, Int16, Int32, Int64, Single, Double, Char, Boolean, SByte, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Delegate, MulticastDelegate, Array, Exception, Type, Enum, System.Runtime.InteropServices.OutAttribute, Attribute, System.Reflection.DefaultMemberAttribute, ParamArrayAttribute, RuntimeTypeHandle, RuntimeFieldHandle, IDisposable, System.Collections.IEnumerable, System.Collections.IEnumerator, Void. Whew!

Comment: Well that what makes software enginering interesting :) Assembling libraries is boring like assembling a PC !

Answer (score 8):

How? Just write the code. Make a namespace called System that contains a class called Object and a class called String, and the compiler will pick that up and use it instead of the framework class library version. *That's how the framework team does it.*  All you have to do is replicate all their work yourself and you too can be in the framework class library providing business.

Note that in many cases the compiler has been designed to expect that the types in the System namespace are *exactly* as they are documented to be. I've had bug reports in the past - extremely confusing bug reports! - where someone has redefined, say, `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>` to have *different* properties and methods than the "real" one, and then they're all surprised and vexed that the compiler generates crazy broken code for a "foreach" loop. If redefining the basic interfaces is the sort of thing you want to do, consider writing your own C# compiler too. Ours is by design not robust in that scenario.

Comment: Note that if you do create a namespace called System and a class called Object, it will still extend `[mscorlib]System.Object`. If this is truly how the Framework team does it, how do they get the compiler to not emit the IL that extends from `[mscorlib]System.Object`?

Comment: Never mind, I found an option in Visual Studio that prevents linking to mscorlib. You guys really have thought of everything!

Comment: Doh! I just noticed that this was in the OP's question. I guess that's what I get for just reading an answer from the RSS feed before the question.