# How to access dotnet's System.Int32 type from within my own System namespace (containing my custom Int32)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

From within my custom top level `System` namespace (where I have also defined struct `Int32`) I am unable to access the dotnet's standard `System.Int32` type.  My own `Systme.Int32` is hiding the dotnet's `System.Int32`. I have tried using `global::` to fully qualify the `System.Int32` name to get to dotnet's standard type , but it still keeps referencing my own type. I cannot find a way around it.
Reading Eric Lippert's 11 year old answer to a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3830520/423632 suggests I need to write my own compiler for this. But it should not be impossible to do.

The following code does not compile , giving the error refering to the first statement in the Main method:
" **error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Int32'** "

```
// DOES NOT COMPILE ! 

using System; 

namespace System
{


    struct Int32
    {

        public override string ToString()
        {

            return "My own Int32 lol";


        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            global::System.Int32 x = 5; // error CS0029 
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            return 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Just for those playing at home. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @TheGeneral Was brushing up on C#'s namespace rules and had this question pop up in my mind. Not immediately using it for any thing, but it is a strange incapability given such a rich and powerful platform (if it indeed is impossible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I found is to use an extern alias:

```
extern alias MSCorLib;
namespace System
{
    struct Int32
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "My own Int32 lol";
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            MSCorLib::System.Int32 x = 5;
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

If you compile this with the [`-reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/inputs#references) option:

```
csc Program.cs -reference:MSCorLib=mscorlib.dll
```

Then it will print 5 as expected.

For `Int32` specifically, you can also just use `int`:

```
int x = 5;
```

Of course, this also applies to `double`, `float`, `short`, etc.